# NoMethodError - template.rb:38:in `<main>': undefined method `template' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

Here is my code I'm trying to run the method but it keeps on kicking out a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'template' for main:Object`

Can someone please help?

```
module Template

  attr_accessor :source_template, :req_id

  def initialize (source_template, req_id)
    @source_template = source_template
    @req_id = req_id
  end

  def self.template(source_template, req_id)
    template = String.new(@source_template)

    template_split_begin = template.index("e")
    template_split_end = template_split_begin + 6
    template_part_one =
      String.new(self.template[0..(template_split_begin-1)])
    template_part_two =
      String.new(self.template[template.length..template_split_end])
    code = String.new(@req_id)
    final_template =
      String.new(template_part_one + code + template_part_two)


    template_split_begin_alt = template.index("a")
    template_split_end_alt = template_split_begin_alt + 9
    template_alt =
      String.new(self.template[0..(template_split_begin_alt-1)])
    template_part_two =
      String.new(self.template[template.length..template_split_begin_alt])
    altcode = code[5..7] - code[0..4]
    final_alt_template =
      String.new(template_part_one_alt + altcode + template_part_two_alt)
  end
end

sample = "Green", 8
template("Blue", 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I need deeper explanation.

1. You can't get the module instance, thus your `initialize` method is meaningless. You should use it only with classes.
2. `attr_accessor :source_template, :req_id` makes no sense in your code
3. `sample = "Green", 8` is unused variable
4. You call `template("Blue", 6)` on an object, not on your `module`, where it's defined, that's why I said you should use `Template.template("Blue", 6)`

If you had changed it, you would haven't got this error anymore. But from your code seems like you are missing basic knowledge of the language, so I would recommend you to read some book about Ruby, before diving into coding.

Comment: It still gives the same NoMethodError for template method. I think my code inside my template method is irrelevant because I can't call a method on itself while still defining it. Right?

Comment: @user1203225 I updated the answer. sorry, but I don't understand your question. In Ruby there is no such thing as "call a method on itself "

Comment: No worries. Thank you for your help and I will look at Learning Ruby the Hard Way.